# Could I pass annotation to child class which extends it?

Tags: java, inheritance, annotations, android-room, java-annotations

I'm lazy person... i just want the simplest way, now i'm learning android room. This might be answered here "[Why is it not possible to extend annotations in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624084/why-is-it-not-possible-to-extend-annotations-in-java)", but it seems like to try pass annotation to another annotation, right? So, Could i pass annotation to the child class for example, here is my parent class 'Model':

```
@Entity
public abstract class Model implements Parcelable{
    @Nullable
    @PrimaryKey
    private Object id;

    public String toJSON(){
        return new Gson().toJson(this);
    }

    public <T> T getId(Class<T>type) {
        if(type.equals(Integer.class)||type.equals(int.class)) {
            return (T) Integer.valueOf(new Double(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(id))).intValue());
        }
        else if(type.equals(Long.class)||type.equals(long.class)) {
            return (T) Long.valueOf(new Double(Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(id))).longValue());
        }
        else if(type.equals(Double.class)||type.equals(double.class)) {
            return (T) Double.valueOf(id.toString());
        }else if(type.equals(UUID.class)){
            return (T) UUID.fromString(String.valueOf(id));
        }
        return type.cast(id);
    }

    public <T> void setId(T id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

I tried to pass `@Entity` to child class.

```
public class Movie extends Model {
    public static final String IDENTIFIER = Movie.class.getSimpleName();
    @SerializedName("popularity")
    private double popularity;
    @SerializedName("vote_count")
    private long voteCount;
    @SerializedName("video")
    private boolean video;
}
```

Because my data access object cannot detect my 'Movie' class, except i'm added Entity annotation

```
@Dao
public interface FavMovieDAO {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM Movie WHERE id = :movieId")
    public Movie find (int movieId);
}
```

If there is no way, i'll declare my entire model class as an Entity... :/. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you want to check out [Embedded](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Embedded)

Comment: If not, maybe [@Inherited](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23973107/how-to-use-inherited-annotation-in-java)