# How to make a 3rd Party Annotation Inheritable

Tags: java, annotations, pojo

I am trying to use @AvroName annotation in java POJO fields. However, I want these POJO fields to be inherited by the subclasses. But @AvroName annotation does not have the @Inherited annotation to it.

Is there a way to make the @AvroName annotation have @Inherited?

I was wondering if I can make a wrapper annotation but not very sure.

```
public abstract class Abc {

  @AvroName(“field1”)
  public String field1;
}
```

```
public class Xyz extends Abc {

  @AvroName(“field2”)
  public String field2;
}
```

I want my Xyz object to have both field1 and field2 with @AvroName properties.

Comment: In Java fields are inherited by subclasses and their annotations don't magically disappear. So the question is: what problem are you trying to solve? Where did you fail?

Comment: I am trying to use a client that needs the @AvroName annotation to resolve the avro schema. However, it is failing if I keep the common fields in Abc abstract class. Essentially i have hierarchical inheritance happening and Abc is the parent class

Answer (score 0):

I am not too sure if I understood the problem correctly. The fields in you Xyz class are both annotated with `@AvroName`, you don't need this annotation to be annotated with `@Inherited`. `@Inherited` only has effect on classes.

Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23973331/8482064) can clear it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

The class `Xyz` has the fields `field2` and `field1` and both are annotated with an `AvroName` annotation.

The following code shows that:

```
public class AnnTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Field[] fields = Xyz.class.getFields();
        for (Field f: fields) {
            System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", f.getName(), Arrays.toString(f.getAnnotations()));
        }
    }
}
```

The output from this code is:

> ```
> field2: [@org.apache.avro.reflect.AvroName("field2")]
> field1: [@org.apache.avro.reflect.AvroName("field1")]
> ```

The problem is that the client you want to use does not correctly handle inherited fields.

---

Note that even if you could add the `@Inherited` annotation to the `AvroName` annotation the behaviour would not change.

The documentation of the [`@Inherited` annotataion](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html) explicitly states:

> Note that this meta-annotation interface has no effect if the annotated interface is used to annotate anything other than a class.